# ViewPager view extending Display

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager

I am new to Android Programming. This might be something simple that I am missing. I have a `ViewPager` within a `CoordinatorLayout`along with a toolbar and tablayout. However the `ViewPager` view seems to extend the display, so any other layout I use to populate the ViewPager gets cut off.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHTtR.png)

### XML code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from the ViewPager.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you, this worked

Comment: @DanielNugent Actually, now it hides the top of the layout.

Comment: Also remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from the Toolbar

Comment: @DanielNugent Still facing same issue, I'm afraid